# The string "Allproducts" isn't included in the URL Redirect in the pager

Tags: pagination, pager

In `CMS > Pages` I've created an `all products` page. The content has this in it:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="100" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

**An example URL:** https://www.awebsite.com/allproducts

It works fine, every product is shown on the page as it should. But, I've a problem with the `pager`. When a user clicks on "show 80 products in page", then the problem appears. The user gets redirected to this url:

An example of the faulty URL: https://www.awebsite.com/?limit=80

As you can see, the `all-products` `isn't included in the url`. Thus, not redirected to the all products page.

I found this articles:

- http://www.noamdesign.com/magento-include-toolbar-and-pagination-when-listing-products/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555157/show-pagination-links-for-product-list-on-a-magento-cms-page

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar not working when you add in content instead of this you can add in update layout xml of your cms page:

Solution for your problem:

1. Go to CMS > Manage Pages and click on the page where you want to display your products.
2. Under the “Design” tab, insert the following code in the “Update Layout XML” field:

   ```
   <reference name="content">
           <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
           <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>100</category_id></action>
               <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
               <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
               <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                   <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                   <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                   <!--
                       <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                       <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                       <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                       <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                       <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                       <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                       <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                   -->
               </block>
               <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
               <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
               <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
               <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
               <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
               <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
               <!-- Since the addColumnCountLayoutDepend does not work, we are manually setting the max columns -->
               <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
           </block>
   </reference>
   ```

Comment: you have close the </reference > tag..Sorry for that.

Comment: please copy paste the above code i have tried it...

Comment: Now try updated snippet it defiantly wroks..

Comment: i have checked on magento 1.9.0.1 and its working perfectly..

Comment: Where you have added the above code?

Comment: CMS > Pages > "The all product page" > Design > layout update XML

Comment: I'm using Magento ver. 1.14.0.1

Comment: Its in enterprise edition..